# Is there a word for a party leader whose outlook might as well be the party's slogan?

Tags: single-word-requests

This person does not even have to hold an official rank. However, he or she would be sufficiently well-known to be appealed to, or referenced, when doubt arises in regard to this or that decision about to be made.

Comment: Do you mean the founder of the party?

Comment: "Leader" is probably as good as anything.  It's a rare enough thing that there's not really a need for multiple words.

Comment: Do you mean that person A lends his name to create a new party? Or the group becomes followers of said leader, and adopt his name? E.g. Thatcherites, Clintonians, Berlusconians

Comment: Can you give examples of what you're describing?

Comment: for example, "Bhartiya Janta party (BJP) belongs to Narendra Modi." In this sentence, Narendra Modi represents his party. As opposed to Narendra Modi belongs to Bhartiya Janta Party (BJP)

Answer (score 2):

How about *epitomizes* or *exemplifies*?  You'd be saying that the person in question is the closest representation of what the party in question stands for.

If you mean more of an ownership definition, you could use *owns* or *dominates*.

Finally, if you really mean that Person A could replace Party A in sentences, perhaps saying Person A is the *embodiment* of Party A?

Answer (score 0):

I'll guess that you don't mean that the person "owns" the party as property to be used for his or her personal aims (which would make them an *autocrat* or even a *dictator* if the party were to exercise political power).

If you mean that the person is the party's figurehead, the public face of the party, and the person with the highest responsibility for the party's conduct and for selecting its most senior personnel, then (in British English at least) this person is called the *leader*. Party leader is an official and formal position to which a person is appointed.